# Unable to debug unit tests in Visual Studio 2022 Mac (preview)

Tags: visual-studio-mac, .net-6.0

I'm developing a solution and I'm using Visual Studio 2022 for the Mac on a Mac Mini M1.
The VS build is 6509 (latest i think).

- I can debug my web-site w/o issue
- I can RUN unit tests w/o issue

But if I try to DEBUG my unit tests (I'm using xunit) I get the following:

*Unable to attach to CoreCLR. Unknown Error: 0x80131c3c*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed this by basically deleting VS and .net and then reinstalling.  The only thing I can figure is that I had the old x86 stuff already installed and when the new M1 stuff went it some of the configuration files got messed up.